# Different versions of the same app depending on device (app store)

Tags: ios, ipad, download, app-store, version

I have submitted my game to the App Store and updated it, now the newest version is the version that every one who downloads my game should get, Right?

Now the problem is, when I download my game from the App Store on my iPad mini I get the correct version, however when I download it from an iPad 2 I get the older version!

That's not supposed to happen, How can I fix it? Also, How can I make sure the newest version of my app is the one everyone gets?(I don't have an iPhone or iPod touch so I can't test to see what version I get from the App Store)