# Same app getting downloaded differently on different devices

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, icloud, itunes-store

My question is [possibly duplicate of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18797981/different-versions-of-the-same-app-depending-on-device-app-store) ,  but unfortunately that does not have any answer and this may be the OFF TOPIC as its related to iTUNES and not with code.

But I am really stuck and expecting some quick help so posting this question.

One of my app is on store with new version  **(2.0 - With New UI)** so my problem is that in One iPad I am getting the ***FREE** icon where I am getting latest version **(2.0)** of my app(directly from store link) and in Another iPad I am getting older version **(1.0 - Old UI)**.

I tried signing in with different Apple Id's and also tried different iCloud id's but no luck.

**Update : Both Devices have iOS 7.0.6**

Can anyone please suggest me the possible solution.

Any help will really be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: When did you push your app ? Maybe new version is simply not yet propagated fully ?

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski i don't think so, as I mentioned in question I can download the latest version in one ipad and its working fine but not in other ipad there I am getting old version as changed UI. And it is in ready to sale state from last 2 days.

Comment: The `"Free"` one indicates to me that it has never been purchased by that Apple Account off the store before, whereas the `"Cloud"` means it has been downloaded on that account before and is can be downloaded from there. I believe that the cloud updates with the latest version automatically but don't hold me to that.

Comment: can you provide screenshots from your app insetad from the app store? And tell us which iOS versions do the different devices you tested have?

Comment: Why do you care ? It's iTunes ... not your app ?

Comment: @jcesar both devices have iOS 7.0.4

Comment: @CW0007007 I think you didn't read my question, at the end of story I am the one who is getting affected because of this scenario.

Comment: Then it might be an apple store problem, contact apple

Answer (score 2):

It is showing the cloud icon on the one because the app has already been downloaded with the account you're signed into on that device. So it is getting the last downloaded version of the app from iCloud. The other one must be signed in with an account that hasn't downloaded it yet, so it is showing the normal download button. On the one that shows the cloud, once you download it you should be able to subsequently download and install the update to your app.

Comment: I was also thinking the same so already tried different Apple Id's and also reset the iCloud account(as mention in question) but no luck.

Comment: What do you mean "no luck"? That's the answer. What problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: @TomHarrington This is not the answer and not solved the issue otherwise I would have accept it. These things I already mentioned in my question. and I posted this question only after trying all the possibilities.

Comment: Actually it is the answer. You don't like it, but that doesn't mean it isn't correct.

Comment: @iLearner This is mentioned in various places on the net that this is the behavior: http://hetzel.net/2013-02-06/icloud-restore-restores-old-app-versions/